# Getting different output for same testcase in hackerrank

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, stack

I'm trying balanced paranthesis [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/balanced-brackets/submissions/code/51170607) in hackerrank.

I'm getting different output for same test case which is very weird !!

This is the sub test case :

```
()[{}()]([[][]()[[]]]{()})([]()){[]{}}{{}}{}(){([[{}([]{})]])}
```

If I run this alone I'm getting the correct answer(In my case Output is `"YES"`)

When this test case is ran along with other test cases I'm getting `"NO"` as output.

This is the actual testcase that I purchased for 5 hackos :

```
21
()[{}()]([[][]()[[]]]{()})([]()){[]{}}{{}}{}(){([[{}([]{})]])}
{][({(}]][[[{}]][[[())}[)(]([[[)][[))[}[]][()}))](]){}}})}[{]{}{((}]}{{)[{[){{)[]]}))]()]})))[
[)](][[([]))[)
]}]){[{{){
{[(}{)]]){(}}(][{{)]{[(((}{}{)}[({[}[}((}{()}[]})]}]]))((]][[{{}[(}})[){()}}{(}{{({{}[[]})]{((]{[){[
()}}[(}])][{]{()([}[}{}[{[]{]](]][[))(()[}(}{[{}[[]([{](]{}{[){()[{[{}}{[{()(()({}([[}[}[{(]})
){[])[](){[)}[)]}]]){](]()]({{)(]])(]{(}(}{)}])){[{}((){[({(()[[}](]})]}({)}{)]{{{
[(})])}{}}]{({[]]]))]})]
[{
{}([{()[]{{}}}])({})
{({}{[({({})([[]])}({}))({})]})}
()[]
{)[])}]){){]}[(({[)[{{[((]{()[]}][([(]}{](])()(}{(]}{})[)))[](){({)][}()((
[][(([{}])){}]{}[()]{([[{[()]({}[])()()}[{}][]]])}
(}]}
(([{()}]))[({[{}{}[]]{}})]{((){}{()}){{}}}{}{{[{[][]([])}[()({}())()({[]}{{[[]]([])}})()]]}}
[(([){[](}){){]]}{}([](([[)}[)})[(()[]){})}}]][({[}])}{(({}}{{{{])({]]}[[{{(}}][{)([)]}}
()()[()([{[()][]{}(){()({[]}[(((){(())}))]()){}}}])]
({)}]}[}]{({))}{)]()(](])})][(]{}{({{}[]{][)){}{}))]()}((][{]{]{][{}[)}}{)()][{[{{[[
)}(()[])(}]{{{}[)([})]()}()]}(][}{){}}})}({](){([()({{(){{
}([]]][[){}}[[)}[(}(}]{(}[{}][{}](}]}))]{][[}(({(]}[]{[{){{(}}[){[][{[]{[}}[)]}}]{}}(}
```

The sub testcase that I've shown is first one in this big one...

This is my java code :

```
package Java.Stacks.Hackerrank_Problems;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 * Created by BK on 06-08-2017.
 */

public class BalancedParanthesis {
    public static void main(String... strings) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tc = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < tc; i++) {
            printAnswer(sc.next());
        }
    }

    private static void printAnswer(String input) {
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        boolean isValid=true;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char currentChar = input.charAt(i);
            if (currentChar == '{' || currentChar == '(' || currentChar == '[') stack.push(currentChar);
            else if (currentChar == '}') {
                if (stack.isEmpty())isValid=false;
                else {
                    if (stack.pop() != '{') {
                        isValid=false;
                    }
                }
            } else if (currentChar == ')') {
                if (stack.isEmpty())isValid=false;
                else {
                    if (stack.pop() != '(') {
                        isValid=false;
                    }
                }
            } else if (currentChar == ']') {
                if (stack.isEmpty())isValid=false;
                else {
                    if (stack.pop() != '[') {
                        isValid=false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(isValid?"YES":"NO");
    }
}
```

Please help me to get rid of this... Thankyou :)

This says it's not working...

[image: Error Image]

Comment: seems to be working fine here http://ideone.com/jOgg4I

Comment: but it's not working in my ide and hackerrank as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to check if stack is empty at the end, this is the code which was accepted at hackerrank

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    static String isBalanced(String s) {
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        boolean isValid=true;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char currentChar = s.charAt(i);
            if (currentChar == '{' || currentChar == '(' || currentChar == '[') stack.push(currentChar);
            else if (currentChar == '}') {
                if (stack.isEmpty())isValid=false;
                else {
                    if (stack.pop() != '{') {
                        isValid=false;
                    }
                }
            } else if (currentChar == ')') {
                if (stack.isEmpty())isValid=false;
                else {
                    if (stack.pop() != '(') {
                        isValid=false;
                    }
                }
            } else if (currentChar == ']') {
                if (stack.isEmpty())isValid=false;
                else {
                    if (stack.pop() != '[') {
                        isValid=false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return (isValid && stack.empty()?"YES":"NO");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
            String s = in.next();
            String result = isBalanced(s);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

notice the small change

> (isValid && stack.empty()?"YES":"NO");

Answer (score 1):

Suggested edit.Please try this.See if it works.

```
int tc = sc.nextInt();
String s=sc.nextLine();//Just for storing the escape character
    for (int i = 0; i < tc; i++) {
        printAnswer(sc.next());
    }
```